# What's different between returning from Object.assign and from customized object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using typeorm in NestJS, in the app.module.ts
I try to initialize my database setting by applying forRootAsync

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: configService.get('database.type'),
        host: configService.get('database.host'),
        port: configService.get('database.port'),
        username: configService.get('database.username'),
        password: configService.get('database.password'),
        database: configService.get('database.database'),
        entities: configService.get('database.entities'),
        synchronize: configService.get('database.synchronize'),
        logging: configService.get('database.logging'),
    }),
}),
```

During compiling I got the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type '(configService: ConfigService) => Promise<{ type: "mysql" | "mariadb" | "postgres" | "cockroachdb" | "sqlite" | "mssql" | "sap" | "oracle" | "cordova" | "nativescript" | "react-native" | "sqljs" | "mongodb" | "aurora-data-api" | "aurora-data-api-pg" | "expo" | "better-sqlite3"; ... 7 more ...; logging: LoggerOptions...' is not assignable to type '(...args: any[]) => TypeOrmModuleOptions | Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ type: "mysql" | "mariadb" | "postgres" | "cockroachdb" | "sqlite" | "mssql" | "sap" | "oracle" | "cordova" | "nativescript" | "react-native" | "sqljs" | "mongodb" | "aurora-data-api" | "aurora-data-api-pg" | "expo" | "better-sqlite3"; ... 7 more ...; logging: LoggerOptions; }>' is not assignable to type 'TypeOrmModuleOptions | Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ type: "mysql" | "mariadb" | "postgres" | "cockroachdb" | "sqlite" | "mssql" | "sap" | "oracle" | "cordova" | "nativescript" | "react-native" | "sqljs" | "mongodb" | "aurora-data-api" | "aurora-data-api-pg" | "expo" | "better-sqlite3"; ... 7 more ...; logging: LoggerOptions; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions>'.
      Type '{ type: "mysql" | "mariadb" | "postgres" | "cockroachdb" | "sqlite" | "mssql" | "sap" | "oracle" | "cordova" | "nativescript" | "react-native" | "sqljs" | "mongodb" | "aurora-data-api" | "aurora-data-api-pg" | "expo" | "better-sqlite3"; ... 7 more ...; logging: LoggerOptions; }' is not assignable to type 'TypeOrmModuleOptions'.
        Type '{ type: "mysql" | "mariadb" | "postgres" | "cockroachdb" | "sqlite" | "mssql" | "sap" | "oracle" | "cordova" | "nativescript" | "react-native" | "sqljs" | "mongodb" | "aurora-data-api" | "aurora-data-api-pg" | "expo" | "better-sqlite3"; ... 7 more ...; logging: LoggerOptions; }' is not assignable to type '{ retryAttempts?: number; retryDelay?: number; toRetry?: (err: any) => boolean; autoLoadEntities?: boolean; keepConnectionAlive?: boolean; verboseRetryLog?: boolean; } & Partial<AuroraDataApiConnectionOptions>'.
          Type '{ type: "mysql" | "mariadb" | "postgres" | "cockroachdb" | "sqlite" | "mssql" | "sap" | "oracle" | "cordova" | "nativescript" | "react-native" | "sqljs" | "mongodb" | "aurora-data-api" | "aurora-data-api-pg" | "expo" | "better-sqlite3"; ... 7 more ...; logging: LoggerOptions; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<AuroraDataApiConnectionOptions>'.
            Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
              Type '"mysql" | "mariadb" | "postgres" | "cockroachdb" | "sqlite" | "mssql" | "sap" | "oracle" | "cordova" | "nativescript" | "react-native" | "sqljs" | "mongodb" | "aurora-data-api" | "aurora-data-api-pg" | "expo" | "better-sqlite3"' is not assignable to type '"aurora-data-api"'.
                Type '"mysql"' is not assignable to type '"aurora-data-api"'.

19             useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
               ~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/interfaces/typeorm-options.interface.d.ts:19:5
    19     useFactory?: (...args: any[]) => Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> | TypeOrmModuleOptions;
           ~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'useFactory' which is declared here on type 'TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions'
```

But if I apply Object.assign() before returning it will pass through

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) =>
        Object.assign({
            type: configService.get('database.type'),
            host: configService.get('database.host'),
            port: configService.get('database.port'),
            username: configService.get('database.username'),
            password: configService.get('database.password'),
            database: configService.get('database.database'),
            entities: configService.get('database.entities'),
            synchronize: configService.get('database.synchronize'),
            logging: configService.get('database.logging'),
        }),
}),
```

Is this because the Object.assign() casting the object to **any** type?
And what's the usual way to initial the typeorm asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I found this thread.

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1119

It says we need to assign the type specifically.

So I changed the type property in the return object:

```
type: configService.get('database.type') as 'mysql',
```

But if I remove the Object.assign(), I still get the same compiling error, and I noticed that the line

```
password: configService.get('database.password')
```

The configService.get() casting to the value to

```
string | (() => string) | (() => Promise<string>);
```

which causes the problem, so I need to pass the type, the final config looks like this:

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: configService.get('database.type') as 'mysql',
        host: configService.get('database.host'),
        port: configService.get('database.port'),
        username: configService.get('database.username'),
        password: configService.get('database.password'),
        database: configService.get<string>('database.database'),
        entities: [configService.get('database.entities')],
        synchronize: configService.get<boolean>('database.synchronize'),
        logging: configService.get<boolean>('database.logging'),
    }),
})
```

But I still have no idea why it casts the password to that strange type.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your log -  `Type '"mysql"' is not assignable to type '"aurora-data-api"'.`

You can refer - [Overriding options defined in ormconfig](https://typeorm.io/#/using-ormconfig/overriding-options-defined-in-ormconfig). Here it has explicitly mentioned an example to append a custom naming strategy or a custom logger.

TypeORM provides the `getConnectionOptions` function that reads connection options from the ormconfig file or environment variables. - [Hint mentioned on TypeORM Integration](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database)

Comment: But I'm using .env and a extra configuration class to initial my setting